# authority problems with calendar, Outlook 2016, Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013, outlook-2016

so I have the following setup:
Server: Windows 2012, Exchange 2013
(problem) Client: Windows 10, Outlook 2016

User A has access to some calendar of other people. Excepting the calendar of User C, it works fine. If User A wants to see the calendar of C, there is a message, respecting the rights. I'm sure, User A has the rights, but there is this error. Other people have no problems to access the calendar from C.

After trying it with a new Outlook profile, I made a try with web app. User A can open the calendar from user C on web app without problems.

Now its going a little bit more confusing. I tried another User on the machine from User A. User M can access the calendar C on his machine, but not on the machine from A.
So I tried User A on the machine of User M. It doesn't work.

So guys, I now its confusing. I read it twice, its really like I wrote above.

Has anyone an idea what I can do? In the event log on the machines are nothing to see, expecting the message respecting the rights.

regards
tux

Comment: Open outlook with user C, and check with who he shared it first, if everyone is there in example..

Comment: well, I did it. its the first thing I checked... all rights are okay.

Comment: it's still actual

Comment: can you add a printscreen (you can hide name) to show the share on the user c mailbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I solved the problem for now.

After a week of ignoring the problem I had a look. All above written problems are there in the same way. But additional, I noticed that it's possible to change an entry of the calendar. However....

At the next step I deactivated the most add-in software for outlook. And now it works.

Fine, isn't it? So now it's confusing again! I activated the add-ins step by step. And it works!! However in my opinion the config is the same as before...

cheers
tux